# SharedPreferences not storing correctly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a problem, I am doing a calculation multiple times, with the outcome each time, once the final calculation has been done, I then want to store the answer in shared preferences, the problem is I keep getting zero.

here is my code for the loop the calculations are made and the shared preferences

**ACTIVITY 1**

```
for (i = 0; i < happyRating.size()-1; i++) {
    int test = happyRating.get(i);


        if (happyRating.get(i) < happyRating.size()) {
            Log.d("TestTrain", "CALLED");
            int x, x1, x2, y, y1, y2;
            double learningRate = -0.00002;
            //double learningRate = -0.00092;

            x1 = happyRating.get(i);
            x2 = happyRating.get(i + 1);
            y1 = iteration[i];
            y2 = iteration[i + 1];

            x = x2 - x1;
            y = y2 - y1;

            if (x == 0) {
                slope = 0;
            } else {
                slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
            }

            double weightAdj = happyRating.get(i) * slope * learningRate;

            weighting = (weighting + weightAdj);
            dynA =  distArray[i] * weighting;

            Log.d("TestInt", "HappyRating (i): " + Integer.toString(test));
            Log.d("WEIGHTING", Double.toString(weighting)); 

            String PREFS1 = "siclPrefs1";
            SharedPreferences siclPrefs1 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS1,0);
            Editor editor = siclPrefs1.edit();
            editor.putFloat("Weight7", (float) weighting);
            editor.commit();

            if (dynA > 1)
            {
                break;
            }

        } else {
            break;
        }

    }
```

I am using sharedpreferences to store a boolean and when I check that in the next activity that's fine. In case there's any conflicts, here's the code for that

```
TrainingDone = true;

    String PREFS = "siclPrefs";
    SharedPreferences siclPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS,0);
    Editor editor = siclPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("Train7", TrainingDone);
    editor.commit();
```

**ACTIVITY 2**

The extraction on the other activity is done as follows

```
       String PREFS = "siclPrefs";
    SharedPreferences siclPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);

    String PREFS1 = "siclPrefs1";
    SharedPreferences siclPrefs1 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS1, 0);

            double weight = (double) siclPrefs1.getFloat("Weight7", 0);
            Boolean train = siclPrefs.getBoolean("Train7", false);
```

The boolean is being extracted fine, however the weight is showing as zero, I understand that this is because it's not there and the default is zero. Can I reuse the editor or is that where I'm falling down?

Regards, 
Gary

Comment: hey, the code for storing SharedPref's is in a loop. are u sure you want that? the same pref's will be overwritten each time. are u getting the value for Weight7 properly each time?

Comment: hi, yep, the value going into Weight7 is weight, which is right, and it's the final overwrite that I want to store and retrieve..is there something obviously wrong?

Comment: If you just want the final one then you should write your editor outside the loop, just for the sake of less useless read/write of your preference.

Comment: I did that, but as I had set the initial weight globally, the global value got stored

Comment: @DJ-DOO if I understood your last comment, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me, if "weight" is globally and is changed inside your "for", then you can save it after... Back to the question, have you tried changing the default value, just to make sure it's not storing zero?

Comment: @Rigotti I haven't tired that yet.  It doesn't make sense to me, I initialise it globally, I then want to build on the initialisation and when the loop exits store the variable in preferences, which is what I had originally, I had the store outside the loop, but what was stored was the global value.  I have printed the weight out globally in the logcat so I do know that this is correct.  I will try changing the default and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this PublicSharePreferences class.

```
public class PublicSharedPreferences {

    public static void setDefaults(String key, String value, Context context) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
      editor.putString(key, value);
      editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {
      SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ACengiz I'll give that a shot later

Answer (score 0):

To get preference use the following:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                  "Package_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to save data to that preference do the following:

```
prefs.edit().putString("Key", "Value").commit();
```

to get value from that preference do the following:

```
prefs.getString("Key", null)
```

Comment: I understand that and the boolean I'm storing and retrieving is correct, it's the weighting that is incorrect...